# How to read function level settings/keys in Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I  have created one Azure Function App and added 2 functions in it. I can keep global level settings and connection strings in AppSettings and Connection strings at Azure Function App level and that I can read in my all functions.

But where I can keep function level settings and how I can read those settings in function.

For example, Settings added for Function 1 can be read in Function 1 and cannot be read in Function 2.

Are there any option to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option to declare separate settings per function by design. You can try to find a solution with a separate settings store like for secrets [Azure KeyVault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/). But you need MSI or access credentials for that as well which are also on Function App level.

I personally would recommend to build up separate Function Apps in order to archive isolation.

Comment: Agree - functions in the same app should be considered equal in terms of security scopes. If trying to keep any permissions or secrets away from two functions they should be in two apps.  That's the right layer for isolation here.